# IPFS private network connect timeout

Tags: ipfs, private-network

I have 2 home PCs with windows 10. I want to create test ipfs private network between 2 nodes.

I downloaded go-ipfs.

`ipfs version 0.6.0`

I executed

```
ipfs init
ipfs bootstrap rm --all
```

I made swarm.key and added node to config.

```
ipfs bootstrap add /ip4/62.122.132.55/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmYY9U3JFuMykjRjKd1jg6aPCmcf2UYpbaS8fHpwkAVvia
```

I checked if port 4001 is listening.

```
TCP    [::]:4001              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

The same I made on the second node.

I started nodes

```
ipfs daemon
```

The result was

```
Initializing daemon...
go-ipfs version: 0.6.0
Repo version: 10
System version: amd64/windows
Golang version: go1.14.4
Swarm is limited to private network of peers with the swarm key
Swarm key fingerprint: 4c11fea5d8ab67ccf08b22a4ee220db3
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.102/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /p2p-circuit
Swarm announcing /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm announcing /ip4/192.168.1.102/tcp/4001
Swarm announcing /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
WebUI: http://127.0.0.1:5001/webui
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready
```

On second node I tried execute

```
    c:\ipfs>ipfs swarm connect /ip4/62.122.132.55/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmYY9U3JFuMykjRjKd1jg6aPCmcf2UYpbaS8fHpwkAVvia
    Error: connect QmYY9U3JFuMykjRjKd1jg6aPCmcf2UYpbaS8fHpwkAVvia failure: \
failed to dial QmYY9U3JFuMykjRjKd1jg6aPCmcf2UYpbaS8fHpwkAVvia: all dials failed
      * [/ip4/62.122.132.55/tcp/4001] dial tcp4 0.0.0.0:4001->62.122.132.55:4001: i/o timeout
    c:\ipfs>
```

After some time daemon showed

```
    Daemon is ready
    2020-07-19T08:43:50.560+0300 [31mERROR[0m  reprovider.simple simple/reprovide.go:108 \ 
failed to reprovide: failed to find any peer in table
```

What I missed?

Comment: can you ping each device from the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you run the following commands?

> ipfs id

https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-id

> ipfs swarm peers

https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-swarm-peers

> ipfs boostrap list

https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-bootstrap